# jq: insert{"key": "value"} pair in the nested structure

Tags: json, jq

I just wonder how we can achieve this with simple online `jq`.

**AS_IS**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "aaa": {
      "xxx": {
        "url": "https://microsoft.com"
      },
      "xxxx": {
        "url": "https://netflix.com"
      }
    },
    "bbb": {
      "xxx": {
        "url": "https://amazon.com"
      }
    },
    "ccc": {
      "xxx": {
        "url": "https://google.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**TO_BE**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "aaa": {
      "xxx": {
        "url": "https://microsoft.com"
      },
      "xxxx": {
        "url": "https://netflix.com"
      }
    },
    "bbb": {
      "xxx": {
        "url": "https://amazon.com"
      }
    },
    "ccc": {
      "xxx": {
        "url": "https://google.com",
        "pass": "abc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I tried so far is

```
.rules[] | select(.xxx.url | try contains("google.com")) | .xxx += {"pass": "abc"}
```

and the output is below, and I successfully insert `"pass": "abc"`.

```
{
  "xxx": {
    "url": "https://google.com",
    "pass": "abc"
  }
}
```

but I want to get the whole lines of code. (Not a part of it)
ref. https://jqplay.org/s/S_UWrrLRl5

Answer (score 1):

The idea is right, but ensure the last update happens without traversing down to the leaf path (at the same level as `xxx`), but relative to the root path by simply wrapping the filter under `(..)`

```
( .rules[] | select(.xxx.url | try contains("google.com")) | .xxx ) += {"pass": "abc"}
```

Always prefer using *exact* match conditions instead of a partial match

```
( .rules[] | select(.xxx.url == "https://google.com") | .xxx ) += {"pass": "abc"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even more "dynamic" approach:

```
walk(if type=="object" 
        and (.url|type)=="string" 
        and (.url|endswith("google.com")) 
     then .pass = "abc" else . end)
```

Of course, depending on the task requirements, a simpler solution such as the following might suffice:

```
.rules.ccc.xxx.pass = "abc"
```